# Compare current Date time in JPA query

Tags: java, jpa

I want to compare the date in database with current dateTime in JPA query :

captureLimitDate < currentDateTime

my requirement is as follows :

database.captureLimitDate : 04/07/2012 19:03:00 
currentDateTime : 04/07/2012 20:03:00

My JPAQuery is this :

```
SELECT o FROM Operation o"
+ " WHERE ( o.merchantId =:merchantId ) AND "
+ "(o.captureLimitDate < currentDateTime ) ";
```

And Operation class has captureLimitDate as java.util.Date

```
    @Generated(value = "XA", comments = "0,_8BedAMXZEeGHf_Dj4YaPyg")
     private Date captureLimitDate;
```

I want to compare both current date and time . will the above query works. ??

Comment: What does your unit test say?

Answer (score 17):

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP must be used to refere to the current date and time in a JPQL query:

```
select o from Operation o
where o.merchantId = :merchantId
and o.captureLimitDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

If the current date and time is in fact a date coming from user input (and which is thus not the current date and time, then you do it like you do for the `merchantId`:

```
select o from Operation o
where o.merchantId = :merchantId
and o.captureLimitDate < :maxDateTime
```

And you set the parameter using

```
query.setParameter("maxDateTime", maxDateTime, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: currentDateTime will be user input , as a parameter to the query . What is to be done in this scenario ?

Answer (score 6):

JPA defines special JPQL expressions that are evaluated to the date and time on the database server when the query is executed:

`CURRENT_DATE` - is evaluated to the current date (a `java.sql.Date` instance).

`CURRENT_TIME` - is evaluated to the current time (a `java.sql.Time` instance).

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` - is evaluated to the current timestamp, i.e. date and time
(a `java.sql.Timestamp` instance).

More info: [Click here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date)